# put_in where leaf nodes are lists, not maps, in Elixir

Tags: elixir

So nested maps cannot be updated directly, and we must use put_in. Example:

```
iex(1)> m = %{a: %{b: 1}}
%{a: %{b: 1}}
iex(2)> m[:a][:b]
1
iex(3)> m[:a][:b] = 2
** (CompileError) iex:3: cannot invoke remote function Access.get/2 inside match
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
iex(3)> m = put_in m, [:a, :b], 2
%{a: %{b: 2}}
```

but what if m looks like this and I want to add the element 2 to the leaf node *list* (not map):

```
iex(7)> m = %{a: %{b: [1]}}
%{a: %{b: [1]}}
iex(8)> put_in m, [:a, :b], 2
%{a: %{b: 2}}
iex(9)>
```

So put_in (logically) replaces the list with the value 2, rather than adding 2 to the list. What I want is this result:

```
%{a: %{b: [1, 2]}}
```

Is this where update_in comes in? How do I do this?

Similarly, how would I do this if the leaf node was a MapSet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want `update_in` here:

```
iex(1)> m = %{a: %{b: [1]}}
%{a: %{b: [1]}}
iex(2)> update_in m, [:a, :b], &(&1 ++ [2])
%{a: %{b: [1, 2]}}
```

For `MapSet`, you'll need to use `MapSet.put/2` instead of `++`:

```
iex(3)> m = %{a: %{b: MapSet.new([1])}}
%{a: %{b: #MapSet<[1]>}}
iex(4)> update_in m, [:a, :b], &MapSet.put(&1, 2)
%{a: %{b: #MapSet<[1, 2]>}}
```